# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, jersey

I want to make a REST API Response in two formats depending on the HttpHeaders of the request :

```
@Context
HttpHeaders headers; 

public Response toResponse(MyValidationException exception) {
   if(headers.getMediaType().toString().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)){
     return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getErrors()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
  }else{
     return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getErrors()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}}
```

It's working for the MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, but for MediaType.APPLICATION_XML I get the following Error :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.HashMap$EntrySet, genericType=class java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.
```

Any Idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have the jaxb dependency in your project?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

If yes, perhaps you could try to wrap the `exception.getErrors()` (which appears to be a Map?) into a `GenericEntity` and giving that entity to the response:

```
GenericEntity<Map<?, ?>> entity = new GenericEntity..

return Response.status(Status.X).entity(entity).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
```

Comment: To cast the exception I wrote : 
GenericEntity<Map<String,String>> entity = (GenericEntity<Map<String,String>>) exception.getErrors(); 
but I got an exception :
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity

Comment: Don't `cast` the object directly, just create it anew:
`GenericEntity<Map<String,String>> entity = new GenericEntity<Map<String,String>>(exception.getErrors()){};`

Comment: I tried but I have the same first problem of the post :/

Comment: In my case, I also had to register the package of the jersey-media-jaxb dependency with the packages method in the JerseyConfig extending ResourceConfig. This may probably depend on the combinations of versions in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `GenericEntity<>`, as described by `ialex`, solved my problem. This is what I did:

```
GenericEntity<List<?>> genericEntity = new GenericEntity<List<?>> (exception.getErrors()) {};
Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(genericEntity).build();
```